# Getting the first field item in Twig

Tags: theming, 8

Why does this work in Twig:

```
{{ content.field_image.0 }}
```

but this does not?

```
{% for item in content.field_gallery|slice(0, 1) %}
<div>{{ item }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I believe you can also use the `|first` filter. See https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/first.html

Comment: @edwardchiapet Tried that, too, to no avail. :\

Answer (score 2):

At a guess...

`field_gallery`, and other fields, are render arrays; that means they have extra elements in them for the meta data (so called `#` properties). `slice` doesn't know the difference between a render array child element, and a `#` property, so it just chops the array up the same way it would any other. The first item in the array is probably a `#` property, hence nothing is being rendered.

The first example works because you're referencing a specific child of the render array by key, which is then rendered immediately.